# Is the "FirstOntario Centre" "in Toronto"?

Tags: canada, toronto, cities

There's a real confusion with the fractal dimension of major world urban centers:  say you live in Williamstown, Victoria.  If you're talking to someone **who is also there in that major urban area**, of course you would not say "I live in Melbourne".  You'd distinguish.

But if talking to **someone from Japan**, you'd just say "Well I'm from Melbourne!" ("Mate!")  It would be absurdist to mention "Williamstown".

So, New Jersey and Brooklyn and Connecticut don't exist to 99.999% of the world, they're just part of "New York".

Is the FirstOntario Centre in Toronto?

[image]

If you live in Toronto, do you "go to concerts at the FirstOntario Centre"?

If I'm going to a concert at the FirstOntario Centre, should I fly "to Toronto"?  Should I "stay at a Toronto hotel"?

Is this FirstOntario Centre thing emotionally and urban-center wise a feature of Toronto? Or it really more of a separate thing - like Dallas / Fort Worth, say? Or is it "actually" part of somewhere else?  (Buffalo? Chicago?)

Comment: I don’t know anyone who thinks CT or NJ is just part of New York. Brooklyn on the other hand can be accurately described that way.

Comment: Of what practical use is this question?..

Comment: @JonathanReez This makes sense to a Melburnian. Toronto to Hamilton is about 70 km, and Melbourne to Geelong is also about 70 km. The big difference is that there is a lot of empty space between Melbourne and Geelong, whereas there's no empty space between Toronto and Hamilton, leading a Melburnian to think that it's all part of the same city.

Comment: @cjdennis yes but why care about the exact terminology in this case? If you want to go there, book a hotel nearby, regardless of what the area is called.

Comment: @JonathanReez There's a big difference if you're booking a journey. A taxi driver mightn't be willing to drive to Geelong, flying to Geelong is a lot different from flying to Melbourne, etc. Calling Geelong part of Melbourne would be misleading and confusing, especially if you're not familiar with the areas.

Comment: @CJDennis whether or not taxi drivers would drive there is indeed a practical question, but it has no relation to naming conventions.

Comment: @CLDennis Actually, Toronto is a leisurely 10-hour drive from Melbourne: https://goo.gl/maps/onY5DX726U72

Comment: It's still an hour or more drive to hamilton from toronto on the 401 west. Pass missisauga, brampton, brantford, oakville, etc. I used to live in north york and sometimes worked in the Brampton Mississauga area so sometimes traffic is crazy on the 401 west bound.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whether or not the residents of Toronto consider this place to be "in Toronto" is of no relevance to travellers.

Comment: @Fattie The introduction talking about where you'd say you lived when talking to a foreigner seemed to imply that these aren't official designations, but simply simplifications made when communicating with people who wouldn't appreciate the distinction. Who else is that relevant to - and who else would make that decision - other than residents?

Comment: the 401 is not getting you to Hamilton. 403 maybe. Really it's QEW, right? But anyway the question isn't how long to takes to drive to Hamilton (and from where? The airport, downtown, Scarborough?)  it's where is the former Copps Coliseum, which this answer doesn't address at all.

Comment: Unless I was speaking to a local, which you've already said you're not, I would just call it Toronto. For basically the same reason, I will tell people that I'm from Boston, even though I'm from the state of New Hampshire, which is not even in the same state as Boston (Massachusetts). Many people have no idea where New Hampshire is, for the same reason that many people would have no idea where Hamilton Ontario is. Close enough to get their bearings, but not specific enough to confuse them with the "oh, okay..." nod of false understanding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [FirstOntario Centre](http://firstontario.centrehamilton.com) is in Hamilton, Ontario, Canada, not Toronto. I've never lived in Hamilton, so I don't know how people talk about it there. It used to be called the Copps Coliseum, and was originally built to try to attract an NHL team to Hamilton.  Hamilton is a city about 70km west of Toronto.

As for your other questions, depending on where you are coming from, you would not necessarily want to fly in to Toronto to go to a concert at the FirstOntarioCentre, (Buffalo might be cheaper, for example) and you would most likely want to stay in Hamilton at least for the day/night of the concert itself.

Wikipedia has more information about it here: [FirstOntario Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FirstOntario_Centre).

Comment: @Fattie Yes I am (although I don't live there now).

Comment: My friend in Hamilton will never say that he is from Toronto, (Toronto area, yes, Toronto, no.) It is an hour by car if you do not get stuck in traffic. I would certainly go for a hotel in Hamilton, if you have a concert in the evening.

Comment: If nothing else the Hamilton hotel will probably be cheaper.

Answer (score 13):

No, Hamilton is not considered part of "Toronto". It is not even part of the [Greater Toronto Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Toronto_Area), which I would use as the limit of areas that are not Toronto but that people might refer to as Toronto nonetheless. If I lived in Hamilton and wanted to explain it to someone in Japan, I might say that I lived "near Toronto".

I live in Toronto and did not even know there *was* a FirstOntario Centre, let alone where it is.

Hamilton has its own airport with several commercial passenger carriers. The main Toronto airport is relatively close, but Niagara Falls Airport, Buffalo, and London, ON airports are close enough that you might consider them. (Which you probably wouldn't from Toronto.)

Comment: people do occasionally refer to the "GTHA" (Greater Toronto-Hamilton Area) (but your answer is perfectly correct). (I live in Hamilton.)

Comment: Yes, to me the fact that there is a GTHA which is distinct from the GTA makes it even clearer that Hamilton is not in "Greater Toronto".

Comment: Great information.

Answer (score 12):

I live in Hamilton. I usually tell people "I live in Hamilton, that's near Toronto".

Assuming you're coming from outside of North America (Australia?), I would recommend flying into Pearson Airport in Toronto (YYZ). It's a global airport with lots of flights. Public transportation to downtown Hamilton is cheap and fairly easy (coach, travel time about 1 hour, about $13 CAD one-way, runs hourly for most of the day [e.g. maybe *not* between 3 and 6 AM]).

Other options:

- Buffalo Airport (BUF) may indeed be cheaper (although not necessarily from outside North America), but travel time is about 1.5 hour [plus a US/Canada land border crossing, which could add significant time if you're unlucky], and last time I checked there weren't good public transport/shuttle options.
- The Hamilton airport (YHM) is unlikely to be a good option from outside Canada; they handle mostly domestic flights, and taxi to downtown might cost more than the bus from Toronto.
- Billy Bishop airport (YTZ) is a small airport in Toronto that serves North American routes only.
- I've never heard of anyone flying into the London (Ontario) airport to get to Hamilton (I've flown out of or into all of YYZ/YHM/YTZ/BUF in the last 8 years). I'd be surprised if they had any flights from outside North America.

If you were coming for a longer visit and wanted to sightsee etc. in Toronto, it wouldn't be insane to stay in Toronto and travel back and forth to Hamilton (about 1 hour by bus or train, although as others have commented it would probably be more expensive). You *could* take taxis back and forth from Hamilton to Toronto but it would be very expensive (certainly more than $50 CAD).

Comment: Fantastic information.